# Storyboards: Push a tableview into a tabbar view

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I'm new to storyboards and I'm trying to achieve this without much progress.

I have a table view controller with cells that currently push into a detail view controller.
What I want to do is to create a tab bar but only for this detail view controller (which will have 3 views that can be navigated using this tabbar).

I can't find the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out that I was setting a property using [segue destinationViewController] but with the new tabbarcontroller in the middle of the flow now I have to do this:

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarViewController = (UITabBarController *) [segue destinationViewController];
    HotelDetailViewController *hotelController = [[tabBarViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    hotelController.hotel = hotel;
```